# unable to satisfy if condition in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, adb

I was trying to execute the following shell script below

```
function Check_Status () {

       if [[ "$(adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed)" =~ "adb: no devices/emulators found" ]]; 
       then
          echo "here"

       else 
            echo "im here"
       fi;
};

Check_Status
```

I'm getting the following output, and I'm expecting to see "here" not "I'm here"

[image: screenshot]

Not sure what could be missing

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: Try installing `shellcheck` and check the script syntax. Did you include bash shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) in the beginning of the script?

Comment: no i didnt include that, im not so much familiar with it anyway

Comment: @ArturMeinild the syntax is fine here, shellcheck wouldn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The text on your pic *looks* the same as the one in your script, yes. But it's a bit hard to be sure from just a pic.

But note how the text comes to your terminal when you run the script? The command substitution is supposed to capture the output, whatever gets caught by it, does not get printed. `adb` probably prints that message to the standard *error*, not standard output, so it doesn't get caught.

You could verify that with something like this:

```
echo "running the command substitution... (errors would print after this line)"
output=$(adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed)
echo "captured output (stdout): '$output'"
```

Then see what comes out where.

And if that's indeed the problem, then you need to redirect the stderr to stdout in the command substitution:

```
if [[ "$(adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed 2>&1)" =~ "adb: no devices/emulators found" ]]; then
    ...
```

Comment: here is my output running the command substitution...
adb: no devices/emulators found
captured output '', I'm not sure why it doesn't catch the output

Comment: 2>&1 solved my issue, could you explain what it means

Comment: @AmrKamel, Unix processes have two distinct output streams, the "standard output" stream that's meant for data, and which gets delivered via pipes and captured by command substitutions, and the "standard error" stream that usually bypasses those. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams So, apparently `adb` treats that situation as an error, and the message to standard output.

Comment: @AmrKamel see [How to redirect stderr to a file](https://askubuntu.com/a/625230)